# what is the path the file system location where SMS messages stored?

Tags: sms

Where in the file system are SMS messages stored? plese list the path

Answer (score 0):

In CM11 (Android KitKat) when using stock messaging app the database file is located at:

/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db

Note that it's not a text file, it's a sqlite database file which needs to be accessed via sqlite-capable front-end (such as sqlite command line client).

Comment: I would like to add that this database is application independent (`.providers`) and usually not readable without either an app with permissions (Message app) or root. It's also neither encrypted nor very well sorted, but holds every message you get (sometimes even hidden ones). Last thing: that path should be valid for all current Android versions (GB, HC, ICS, JB, L).

Comment: You're right it's application independent but as far as I know there are third party apps that use their own storage and sometimes even delete the messages from the `providers` storage.